# How can I display a system wide announcement/banner in my GWT app

Tags: java, gwt

Having an existing GWT what kind of pattern should I follow if I want to display to all the users a system wide message like:

```
System is undergoing maintenance, excuse the potential slowdown here and there.
```

For new users loading the app I can think of ways of pre-populating their initial page, but for users that already have loaded their SPA page then I cannot think of any elegant way to push the message.

And an equally elegant way to retract the message, when the "maintenance" ends some time later on.

Should I use a timer and ask the server a list of messages to display, and have it run in the background...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is IMHO the old way to do this kind of things (polling), but the elegant and modern way is to use server side events via html5 (using something like [atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-started-with-HTML5-Server-Sent-Events-(SSE))) or any [websockets simple gwt library](https://github.com/sksamuel/gwt-websockets)), etc. If you follow this pattern, check also this [other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359786/gwt-servlet-based-notification-server-event-bus).

Comment: I use signalR for this (which is proprieraty MS software) wrapped in GWT.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have other instant server-to-client messages to receive, a simple polling mechanism is most easy to implement and understand. More complex solutions that support instant server-to-client messages are websockets / server side events / long polling.

Also note:
If you are using GWT RPC Services, swapping the backend for a running client will result in a [IncompatibleRemoteServiceException](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IncompatibleRemoteServiceException.html), if ...

> [...] One of the types used in the RemoteService method invocation has had fields added or removed. [...]

The message of this exception reads "This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on your browser." You might want to check for this Exception in the onFailure methods and (ask the user to) reload. See the link for details in which other cases this exception occurs.